# Powershell print a text before foreach runs

Tags: powershell

Can we print a text inside foreach once

can someone give an idea

This is a part of my code

```
$MultiArray = @(
             ("$out1"+"`n"),
             ("$out"+"`n"),
             ("$out2"+"`n")

        )
        $newArray3 = foreach ($_ in $MultiArray) { if (![String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)){ $_} }


        foreach($array in $newArray3)
    {
        $variable++
        $asd = $variable | ForEach-Object {'{0:d3}' -f [int]$_}

        $finalOutput = "$asd" + $array
        echo $finalOutput
    }
```

For the finaloutput variable I need to print a text once on the top
since its a loop it runs again and again

This is my output
Before this gets executed, I need to print a heading at the top once

```
001  AX       AA    C        00:00:00:00 00:00:03:48 00:00:00:00 00:00:04:18
* FROM CLIP NAME: 1aef53e6-92ac-4d28-89f8-4cce28fa0f58.m4a

002  AX       V     C        02:00:05:15 02:00:11:15 00:00:00:00 00:00:06:00
* FROM CLIP NAME: 1aef53e6-92ac-4d28-89f8-4cce28fa0f58.jpg

003  AX       AA/V  C        00:00:00:00 00:00:07:64 00:00:06:00 00:00:15:04
* FROM CLIP NAME: 1aef53e6-92ac-4d28-89f8-4cce28fa0f58.mp4

004  AX       AA    C        00:00:00:00 00:00:03:46 00:00:15:04 00:00:19:20
* FROM CLIP NAME: 9a52a954-ffe9-4420-a701-68988923f81f.m4a

005  AX       V     C        02:00:05:15 02:00:11:15 00:00:15:04 00:00:21:04
* FROM CLIP NAME: 9a52a954-ffe9-4420-a701-68988923f81f.jpg
```

Thank you very much..

Comment: To help you, I think you need to show us examples of what is in `$out`, `$out1` and `$out2`. It would also help if you show us the desired output

Comment: @Theo tks for your quick replay will upload the full code

Comment: @Theo have added the full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty way would be using a a counter and if statement to only print on the first iteration of the loop like so:

```
$Counter = 0
foreach($Array in $NewArray3){
    if($Counter -eq 0){
        Write-Host "HEADING"
    }
    # do the rest of the thigns
    $Counter++
}
```

However, I would recommend looking into organizing your data in PSObjects. The above is not going to be very sustainable if the length of your output changes or someone uses a different width on their terminal etc.